# Laravel URL wildcard changes to "16" when a form (wire:submit.prevent) is submitted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I created a form in **Laravel Livewire** at https://upzarpay.com/invoices/4ILNTOX.
After opening the link click on the button "Easypaisa" and then Send OTP.
The Easypaisa form has `wire:submit.prevent`.
After submitting the form the URL in the browser URL bar changes to `https://upzarpay.com/invoices/17` or `https://upzarpay.com/invoices/16`.
I don't know why the invoice token wildcard `https://upzarpay.com/invoices/{invoice_token}` changes when I submit the form.
**Here is the Source Code:**
*invoice/show.blade.php*

```
@if($easypaisa_screen == 1)
<form class="px-6 py-4 border-t-2" wire:submit.prevent="easypaisa_verify">
    <x-jet-label for="phone_number" value="{{ __('Enter your phone number') }}" />
    <x-jet-input id="phone_number" type="number" class="block mt-1" wire:model.defer="phone_number" />
    <x-jet-input-error for="phone_number" class="mt-2" />
    <button type="submit" wire:loading.attr="disabled"
            class="disabled:opacity-50 mt-1 bg-blue-500 shadow-md text-white mb-4 px-2 py-1 font-bold ">
        Send OTP
    </button>
</form>
@endif
```

*Invoice/Show.php*

```
public function easypaisa_verify() {
    $this->validate([
        'phone_number' => 'required|numeric'
    ]);
    $this->easypaisa_screen = 2;
}
```

Please let me know how can I fix this and why is it happening.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be better if you include the relevant code of your app.

Comment: I've added the source code.